# write this line of jQuery in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me write this line of jQuery in javascript. It applies a single rule of styling to a class.

`$('.dataCard').css('visibilty', 'visible !important');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `!important` doesn't apply when setting styles with javascript, it would be something like this

```
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dataCard');

 for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
      elems[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
 }
```

Comment: A bit of a different way to run your `for` loop.  Why go unconventional (which makes it harder to read for people not familiar with that style)?

Comment: @jfriend00 if they're not familiar, they can look up what it means, and suddenly, it's familiar..?

Comment: @jfriend00 - That's the way I always iterate over nodeLists to make sure I don't run into problems. Of course, querySelectorAll doesn't return a live nodeList, so it's not an issue, but if you switch to getElementsByClassName it is, so I believe it's just good practice to be consistent.

Comment: @RUJordan - there are far, far, far fewer people familiar with this style of iterating.  It uses a side effect of a boolean test in order to decrement the loop variable.  Yes, it works, but it's not as readable as other methods.  Works fine.  I would make a different choice for more readable code.  I do understand the advantage of reverse iteration in live nodeLists, yet that isn't needed here for a couple reasons.  Perhaps I value readability of code to others more than some.  Might have something to do with all the years of managing a team of developers.

Comment: @jfriend00 this might be off topic, but how can you define readability when people are at such vastly different skill levels?

Comment: @RUJordan - On a large team, what is important is something that will be readable to everyone who might ever be associated with the project.  That means readable by the lowest skill level that will work on the project (which may vary by team/project).  There's nothing technically wrong with what adeneo chose here - I would just use something more conventional because it would be quicker to comprehend by someone who isn't use to this style.  I didn't mean to make this big a deal out of this.

Comment: And I'm not bashing you, I've always had an .. "issue" with readability but it's usually misled

Comment: I think writing any example code with a style that is not the most conventional detracts from what you are trying to show. Yes, it's not  hard, but I had to look twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a general purpose function that can replace what you had in jQuery, you could do this:

```
function setStyle(elemOrSelector, prop, val) {
    var items;
    if (typeof elemOrSelector === "string") {
        // run selector query
        items = document.querySelectorAll(elemOrSelector);
    } else if (elemOrSelector.nodeName) {
        // must be single DOM object
        items = [elemOrSelector];
    } else if (elemOrSelector.length)
        // must be an array or nodeList
        items = elemOrSelector;
    } else {
        // don't know what it is
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].style[prop] = val;
    }
}

setStyle('.dataCard', "visibility", "visible");
```

This general purpose function allows you to pass either a DOM element, an array like list of DOM elements or a selector string.

---

If you don't want the general purposeness, then you can just use this:

```
function setStyle(selector, prop, val) {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].style[prop] = val;
    }
}

setStyle('.dataCard', "visibility", "visible");
```

Comment: selector is not defined

Comment: @gomangomango more lines of code != complicated. It's actually very simple function.

Comment: @gomangomango - It's much more general purpose and can be used for lots of operations with a variety of input formats much like the jQuery function that it replaces.  I prefer general purpose code that can be reused rather than lots of pieces of  code that each have to be copied and changed to do something slightly different.

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay. I'll study it and learn from it. I am interested in learning the js behind jquery.

Comment: If you're going this route and mimmicking jQuery, why not do something like this -> ***http://jsfiddle.net/NPBDz/***

Comment: @adeneo - Because I've been warned over the years about the issues of adding non-standard methods to built-in objects (collisions with other implementations and libraries, problems with people using laxy `for-in` iteration, etc...).  So, I don't do that (and jQuery doesn't either).

Comment: I have no qualms in prototyping on native methods as long as I keep track of what is where etc. and of course jQuery doesn't do this as it has it's own global, the `$` to prototype all it's methods onto.

Comment: @adeneo - That's fine - it can be made to work.  You just also have to keep track of every place any other library you use does this or any other developer in your project does this too in order to avoid any accidental collisions.  I prefer not to rely on that.

Comment: But that's the other guys, they are stupid and should avoid this at all cost, I on the other hand can screw up native stuff as much as I want.

Comment: @adeneo - Those "other" guys.  Always causing problems for the rest of us :)